# File uploads but the multer code is not executed | Node + multer + express + formdata

Tags: node.js, reactjs, forms, express, multer

I am uploading a video file to a local folder using `form`, `multer`, `express` and `nodejs`.

The video file gets uploaded to the local folder - everytime I upload it through the form. However, the code inside `upload` executes only occasionally. Once in 5 times. i.e. `console.log('33');` inside the `app.post` doesn't always get printed. However, `console.log('1')` (the one inside `post` and before `upload`) works everytime.

`server.js` code

```
var Express = require('express');
var multer = require('multer');
var mkdirp = require('mkdirp');
var app = Express();

var cors = require('cors');    
app.use(cors());
    
var Storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function(req, file, cb) {
        var dir = './client/public/video/';
        mkdirp(dir, function(err) {
        if(err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
        cb(null, dir);
    });
    console.log("Upload: saved to " + dir + file.originalname);
    },
        filename: function(req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, file.fieldname + "_" + Date.now() + "_" + file.originalname);
    }
});

var upload = multer({
    storage: Storage
  }).single("file");


app.post("/api", function(req, res) {
    console.log('1');

    upload(req, res, function(err) {
    console.log('33');
    if (err) {
             return res.end("Something went wrong!");
         }

    return res.status(200).end("File uploaded successfully!.");
  });

 });

var server = app.listen(9000, function () {
  console.log('app listening at 9000');
});
```

`app.js` code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import axios from "axios";

class App extends Component {
    state = {
        file: null
    };

    handleOnChange = e => this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

    handleOnUploadFile = e => this.setState({ file: e.target.files[0] });

    handleOnSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const formData = new FormData();

        formData.append("file", this.state.file);
        
        axios
        .post("http://localhost:9000/api", formData, {
         headers: {
            'accept': 'video/mp4',
    'Accept-Language': `en-US,en;q=0.8`,
    'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${formData._boundary}`,
         }  
        })
        .then(res => console.log(res.data))
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
    };

    render() {
        return (
                <form>
                    <input type="file" encType="multipart/form-data"
                    name="file"
                    accept="video/mp4"
                   onChange={this.handleOnUploadFile}/>
                
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.handleOnSubmit}>
                        Submit
                    </button>
                </form>
            );
        }
}

export default App;
```

I am new to react/node js. Tried a lot of suggestions from other posts, but couldn't find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `async` and `await`.

`server.js`

```
var Express = require('express');
var multer = require('multer');
var mkdirp = require('mkdirp');
var app = Express();

var cors = require('cors');    
app.use(cors());
    
var Storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function(req, file, cb) {
        var dir = './client/public/video/';
        mkdirp(dir, function(err) {
        if(err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
        cb(null, dir);
    });
    console.log("Upload: saved to " + dir + file.originalname);
    },
        filename: function(req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, file.fieldname + "_" + Date.now() + "_" + file.originalname);
    }
});

var upload = multer({
    storage: Storage
  }).single("file");


app.post("/api", function(req, res) {
    console.log('1');

    upload(req, res, function(err) {
    console.log('33');
    if (err) {
             return res.end("Something went wrong!");
         }

    return res.status(200).end("File uploaded successfully!.");
  });

 });

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  console.log('1');

  return res.status(200).json({});
});

var server = app.listen(9900, function () {
  console.log('app listening at 9900');
});
```

`App.js`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import axios from "axios";

class App extends Component {
    state = {
        file: null
    };

    handleOnChange = e => this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

    handleOnUploadFile = e => this.setState({ file: e.target.files[0] });

    handleOnSubmit = async e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const formData = new FormData();

        formData.append("file", this.state.file);
        
        await axios
        .post("http://localhost:9900/api", formData, {
         headers: {
            'accept': 'video/mp4',
    'Accept-Language': `en-US,en;q=0.8`,
    'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${formData._boundary}`,
         }  
        })
        .then(res => console.log(res.data))
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <h1>{"<b>hello</b>".bold()}</h1>
                <form>
                    <input type="file" encType="multipart/form-data"
                    name="file"
                    accept="video/mp4"
                   onChange={this.handleOnUploadFile}/>
                
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.handleOnSubmit}>
                        Submit
                    </button>
                </form>
            </>
            );
        }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Probably is something else, but I tested and it printed the expected results:

```1 Upload: saved to ./client/public/video/tf_java_api.mp4 33```

Comment: What is the size of the video file that you are uploading? My filesize is ~50MB. Tried uploading a 4MB file. Getting `33` as output then. Not when uploading the 50MB file.

`app listening at 9000`
`1`
`Upload: saved to ./client/public/video/2019-10-13-213106.mp4`
`33`
`1`
`Upload: saved to ./client/public/video/2019.mp4`
`1`
`Upload: saved to ./client/public/video/2019.mp4`

`2019.mp4` is 50MB in size. As per multer documentation, filesize can be `infinity`

Comment: I used a 212 MB .mp4 file.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a promise for your upload function:

```js
var Express = require('express');
var multer = require('multer');
var mkdirp = require('mkdirp');
var app = Express();

var cors = require('cors');    
app.use(cors());
    
var Storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function(req, file, cb) {
        var dir = './client/public/video/';
        mkdirp(dir, function(err) {
        if(err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
        cb(null, dir);
    });
    console.log("Upload: saved to " + dir + file.originalname);
    },
        filename: function(req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, file.fieldname + "_" + Date.now() + "_" + file.originalname);
    }
});

var upload = multer({
    storage: Storage
  }).single("file");


app.post("/api", function(req, res) {
    console.log('1');
    
    upload(req, res).then((file, err) => {
    console.log('33');
    if (err) {
             return res.end("Something went wrong!");
         }

    return res.status(200).end("File uploaded successfully!.");
    })



 });

var server = app.listen(9000, function () {
  console.log('app listening at 9000');
});
```

Another idea would be to wrap the upload itself in a promise:

```
var Storage = multer.diskStorage({
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    destination: function(req, file, cb) {
            var dir = './client/public/video/';
            mkdirp(dir, function(err) {
            if(err) {
               reject(err)
            }
            cb(null, dir);
        });
        console.log("Upload: saved to " + dir + file.originalname);
        },
            filename: function(req, file, callback) {
            resolve(callback(null, file.fieldname + "_" + Date.now() + "_" + file.originalname);)
        }
    })
    });
```